# How to get a X-Auth-Token in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to call an API which emits and Header X-Auth-Token.
My questions:

How to get a X-Auth-Token in JavaScript?

Comment: You haven't provided enough information in this question. Please include more details and a larger code sample of what you have tried. Also include details about the API that you are calling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing HTTP Headers in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript)

Comment: This isn't quite an exact duplicate, but the highest rated answer on that question answers this one.

Comment: I would need a general answer as I cannot provide the API right now, sorry about that.